# Can't Display HTML context into the Text Area

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, tinymce

Hi everyone I have been trying to display HTML context into the TinyMCE text area. When I choose the line for editing first time it displays the data but,  after I choose different row it can't get the context. Any Help would be appreciated. Here are my component and HTML that I have created. I am trying to display context when clicking the edit button.

```js
import { Component, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy, Input, Output, EventEmitter, ElementRef, provide } from 'angular2/core';
import { RdComponent, RdLib } from '../../../../../node_modules/mulberry/core';

declare let tinymce: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'aril-mail-template',
  template: `<textarea contentEditable="true" style="height:30em"><p>{{model}}</p></textarea>`
})

export class MailTemplatesComponent extends RdComponent {

  @Input("rd-model") model;
  @Input("rd-default") default;
  @Input("rd-required") required;
  @Output("mail-template-save") mailTemplateSave: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  editor;
  elementRef: ElementRef;

  constructor(elementRef: ElementRef) {
    super()
    this.elementRef = elementRef;
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    tinymce.init({
      selector: 'textarea',
      height: "30em",
      menubar: true,
      plugins: [
        'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
        'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen hr',
        'insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste',
        'wordcount'
      ],
      toolbar: 'bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image code',
      table_toolbar: "tableprops cellprops tabledelete | tableinsertrowbefore tableinsertrowafter tabledeleterow | tableinsertcolbefore tableinsertcolafter tabledeletecol",
      powerpaste_allow_local_images: true,
      powerpaste_word_import: 'prompt',
      powerpaste_html_import: 'prompt',
      content_css: [
        '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,300i,400,400i',
        '//www.tinymce.com/css/codepen.min.css'],

      setup: editor => {
        this.editor = editor;
        editor.on('init', () => {
          this.model && this.editor.setContent(this.model, { format: 'raw' });
        });
        editor.on('change', () => {
          const content = editor.getContent();
          this.mailTemplateSave.emit(content);
        });
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    tinymce.remove(this.editor);
  }

}
```

```html
<rd-service-provider #mailTemplateProvider rd-client-side-paging [rd-service-proxy]="clientSideProxy" [rd-page-size]="25"
  (rd-init)="mailTemplateProvider.call(getMailTemplates())">
</rd-service-provider>
<rd-service-provider #deleteMailTemplateProvider [rd-service-proxy]="serviceProxy" (rd-success)="toastr.info(translate('İşlem Başarıyla Sonlandırıldı')); mailTemplateProvider.call(getMailTemplates())"></rd-service-provider>
<rd-service-provider #saveMailTemplateProvider [rd-service-proxy]="serviceProxy" (rd-success)="toastr.info(translate('Mail Şablonu Başarıyla Oluşturuldu.')); mailTemplateProvider.call(getMailTemplates())"></rd-service-provider>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <rd-portlet [rd-text]="translate('Mail Şablonları')" rd-color="green" rd-icon="fa fa-envelope">
      <rd-tools>
        <rd-tool rd-icon="icon-plus" rd-color="white" [rd-tooltip]="translate('Yeni Şablon Ekle')" rd-animate="flash infinite" (rd-click)="data;showMailTemplate=true;console.log(data)"></rd-tool>
        <rd-tool rd-type="refresh" *ngIf="mailTemplateProvider.content.state.serviceCalled"></rd-tool>
        <rd-tool rd-type="collapse" [rd-default-collapse]="false"></rd-tool>
      </rd-tools>

      <rd-body>
        <rd-grid #grid [rd-provider]="mailTemplateProvider" rd-enableSorting="true" [rd-block]="mailTemplateProvider.content.state.waitigForResponse">
          <rd-grid-column [rd-text]="translate('Mail Türü')" rd-key="EmailType">
            <template #item>
              <rd-value rd-type="text" [rd-model]="item.EmailType"></rd-value>
            </template>
          </rd-grid-column>
          <rd-grid-column [rd-text]="translate('Mail Konusu')" rd-key="MailSubject">
            <template #item>
              <rd-value rd-type="text" [rd-model]="item.MailSubject"></rd-value>
            </template>
          </rd-grid-column>
          <rd-grid-column rd-type="operations">
            <template #item>
              <rd-button rd-icon="fa fa-pencil" rd-icon-color="yellow" rd-size="small" [rd-tooltip]="translate('Düzenle')" (rd-click)="data = item;showMailTemplate=true;console.log(data)"></rd-button>
              <rd-button rd-icon="fa fa-trash-o" rd-icon-color="red" rd-size="small" [rd-tooltip]="translate('Sil')" (rd-confirm-popover)="$event ? deleteMailTemplateProvider.call(deleteMailTemplates(item.Serno)) : null"></rd-button>
            </template>
          </rd-grid-column>
        </rd-grid>
      </rd-body>
    </rd-portlet>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-8" *ngIf="showMailTemplate">
    <rd-portlet [rd-text]="translate('Mail Şablonu Tanımlama')" rd-color="green" rd-icon="fa fa-envelope">
      <rd-body>
        <rd-form>
          <rd-body>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="col-md-6" style="padding:0%">
                    <rd-field [rd-text]="translate('Mail Türü')"></rd-field>
                    <rd-input-select [(rd-model)]="data.EmailType" rd-form-data="EmailType" rd-display="Value" rd-value="Key" [rd-items]="mailTemplatesList">
                    </rd-input-select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <rd-field [rd-text]="translate('Mail Konusu')"></rd-field>
                    <rd-input-text [(rd-model)]="data.MailSubject" rd-form-data="MailSubject" [rd-required]="true"></rd-input-text>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <rd-field [rd-text]="translate('Mail İçeriği')"></rd-field>
                  <aril-mail-template [(rd-model)]="data.MailContent" (mail-template-save)="mailContent = $event" [rd-required]="true"></aril-mail-template>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </rd-body>
          <rd-footer>
            <rd-submit [rd-text]="translate('Kaydet')" rd-size="medium" (rd-click)="saveMailTemplateProvider.call(saveMailTemplates($event, mailContent))"></rd-submit>
            <rd-clean [rd-text]="translate('Temizle')" rd-size="medium"></rd-clean>
          </rd-footer>
        </rd-form>
      </rd-body>
    </rd-portlet>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please delete angularjs tag from it because angular2/4 has nothing to do with angularjs.

Comment: @ BT101 Yes, I know it is not AngularJs. I have used AngularJs in the past and now I am using Angular2 that's why I thought that maybe someone in AngularJs community could help.

Comment: `<rd-button rd-icon="fa fa-pencil" rd-icon-color="yellow" rd-size="small" [rd-tooltip]="translate('Düzenle')" (rd-click)="data = item;showMailTemplate=true;console.log(data)"></rd-button>` is this your edit button?

Comment: Yes it is my edit button.

Comment: So this is some sort of a table or grid with multiple entries and when you're selecting one of it through the button, you want to show the details of the selected entry in your `div` with `*ngIf="ShowMailTemplate"`, correct? But the mail template only shows the email type and subject, but the mail content is not correctly displayed when the data changes, only when the button is clicked for the first time, right?

Comment: Yes, you understand the whole problem very clear. That what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: I have added   
ngOnChanges(changes) {
    if (tinymce.activeEditor)
      tinymce.activeEditor.setContent(this.model);
  }
After ngOnInit and it worked for a bit but after than problem occured again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now the problem that I see is that you're trying to init a new tinymce editor when your data changes, but the editor already exists and therefore the `editor.on('init'...)` is not called again. The problem only occurs when you switch to another Email template after tinymce was initialized already, but works fine when the first row is selected.

So basically calling `tinymce.init` the first time works fine, calling it *again* later does not. The `MailTemplatesComponent` stays the same when switching to another row, it's not changing, only the data in it, so its reference to `editor` will also be kept and not destroyed, which is why calling `init` again is probably not working. tinymce probably thinks, hey I already have initialized that, I don't have to do it again.

Here are two possible solutions I see. First one is to remove the editor on every ngOnChanges and reinit again.

```
ngOnChanges() {
    if(this.editor){
        tinymce.remove(this.editor);
    }
    tinymce.init({
        ....
    });
}
```

But that seems to be a little overkill. Second thing is what I also would recommend. Check if the editor of the component is already existing. If so, don't try to init again, but just set the content.

```
ngOnChanges() {
    if(this.editor){
        this.editor.setContent(this.model);
    } else {
        tinymce.init({
            ....
        });
    }
}
```

## edit

Now when you want to create a new MailTemplate you have to override the current values so that the `ngOnChanges` function is triggered. Currently you're not changing the `data` object that is bound.

```
<rd-tool ... (rd-click)="data;showMailTemplate=true;console.log(data)"></rd-tool>
```

You can see you're not setting data to anything. To clean this up a bit, I would take the code inside your `(rd-click)` event and put it into a function in your component. In that function I would then **update the data** by giving it **empty values**. This way the `ngOnChanges` function is triggered and your new MailContent value (which we just set to an empty string) will be set to the tinymce editor.

```
createNewTemplate(){
    this.data = {
        EmailType: "", 
        MailSubject: "", 
        MailContent: ""
    };
    this.showMailTemplate=true;
    console.log(this.data);
}
```

Then call this function in your html `(rd-click)` binding.

```
<rd-tool ... (rd-click)="createNewTemplate()"></rd-tool>
```

Comment: Thank you, @Benedikt it is now working thanks to your help I have managed to solve the problem. If you don't mind I have another problem to discuss with you. As you can see above HTML I am also trying to create a blank editor to fill the data by myself. With that code.

But it is same as the previous problem in the fir call it created a blank editor and when I call an editor by click event then after calling another blank editor it returns current rows data. 
Any suggestion?

Comment: Creating blank editor.
<rd-tool rd-icon="icon-plus" rd-color="white" [rd-tooltip]="translate('Yeni Şablon Ekle')" rd-animate="flash infinite" (rd-click)="data;showMailTemplate=true;console.log(data)"></rd-tool>

Comment: `<rd-tool rd-icon="icon-plus" rd-color="white" [rd-tooltip]="translate('Yeni Şablon Ekle')" rd-animate="flash infinite" (rd-click)="data;showMailTemplate=true;console.log(data)"></rd-tool>` this line, right?

Comment: Thank you very much @Benedikt now, it is working without error. I appreciate your help and consideration.

Answer (score 0):

You can't define what the editor does on `init` *inside* the editor you're trying to initialize. That doesn't make sense.